# Is it possible to turn off and on all the // comments at once on Visual Express C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# hide and unhide comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696586/c-sharp-hide-and-unhide-comments)

Is it possible to turn off and on all the `//` comments at once on Visual Express C#? I comment my code a lot and being able to turn off all of them at once would really help my workflow.

Comment: Not sure it's an exact duplicate, as he's asking for *all* comments, not just those selected.

Comment: @harriyott sorry I think it is a duplicate, I didn't think of the word `hide`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the lines then:

<kbd>Ctrl + K + U</kbd>

And the opposite:

<kbd>Ctrl + K + C</kbd>

You can find the shortcuts also through the menus - Edit -> Advanced -> ... The shortcuts are listed next to the commands.

And of course, these are also on the Text Editor toolbar:

[image: comment buttons on toolbar]

Comment: How does that work on *all* comments?

Comment: @harriyott - As I posted at the very start: `Select the lines`. I suspect that the OP doesn't need to comment/uncomment all lines in a solution, project or even a single file.

Comment: Reading the question, I thought that was exactly what he was asking. He used the word "all" twice.

Comment: Hi @harriyott and oded, I did want to hide all the comments at once but your replies were very helpful. One thing though, I got a white rectangle with rounded corners in my breakpoint column, what is that?

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani - Sounds like a different question ;) Why not post that with an image of what you mean?

Comment: Thanks @Oded, I got it when typing ctrl+K+U, probably in a wrong way. I will look into it more :)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way might be to use compiler directives instead of comments, e.g.

```
#ifdef commentedCode
Console.WriteLine("This is a comment");
#endif
```

Then, in your project settings, on the Build property page, add `commentedCode` to the Conditional compilation symbols to include the code, and remove it to ignore the code. Not exactly what you asked, but probably quicker than editing multiple files with comments.

Comment: Actually, that is not simpler in most use cases.

Comment: Indeed, not in most cases. But I don't often see coders comment out several blocks of code - I was addressing the *all* part of the question, which the `Ctrl + K + C` answer doesn't address.