# What is this arrow in the code editor's gutter that allows collapsing code blocks called? How can I collapse arbitrary blocks?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-folding

What do you call this?

[image: screenshot of the arrow]

I want to organize my code, and be able to click that little arrow and shadow certain things onto it, take this for example, I want to hide it under my comment `# Words` like this:

[image: screenshot of what I want to hide]

I use visual studio code and I'm working with python.

Some keywords that might be related: Bookmarks, whatever popovers are, and 'ribbons'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597272/836330 - folding arbitrary blocks of code.  And https://stackoverflow.com/a/72954133/836330.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called ["code folding"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding).

To do it with arbitrary blocks of lines of code, there is built-in functionality for *some programming languages*, which you can read more about [in the VS Code docs on editor folding regions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_editor). The general patterns is that you create "marker" comments around the block: one like `#region`, and one like `#endregion`. The current languages supporting markers at the time of this writing (according to the documentation) are JS, TS, C#, C, C++, F#, PowerShell, and VB.

For other languages, you should be able to achieve that with [the `maptz.regionfolder`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder) extension or other similar ones.