# Visual Studio 2015: hide summary text in collapsed comments

Tags: visual-studio-2015, settings

How can I hide "Some long text"?
Are there any options in settings of Visual Studio 2015?

Code in collapsed state becomes messy if you have really long summary sections.

[image: Screenshot with code]

It is not related to method body. It is only about how summary looks in collapsed state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have Visual Studio hide summary sections by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954434/is-it-possible-to-have-visual-studio-hide-summary-sections-by-default)

Comment: @ErikKralj Unfortunately.. No.. There are no anything about method body in my question. It is related only to "comments" (how summary looks in collapsed state). And all is around VS2015.. this is their new "feature"...  But thank you for participation.